# How to interleave php files which each other & Check URL for parameter?

Tags: php, html, css

I need to explain what I wanna do, before I can ask my question, so pls bear with me. I think I have a fundamental thinking error.

I am trying to make a simple fakebook site and I have trouble with the folder structure.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
index.php
assets
subpages
--landingpage.php
--timeline.php
--profiles
  --assets
  --profilename1
    --timelineprofilename1.php
    --photosprofilename1.php
  --profilename2
  ...
```

So what i wanna do:

The user gets to the main page.
It is the index.php file.

The content of `index.php` is in

```
subpages/landingpage.php
```

So whenever the users opens the website, he gets per default the landingpage.php which has 3 pictures on it which contain Links to the profiles and their timelines.

Now i want to do the following:

**1. Is this way of thinking correct or should everything be displayed at the root in the index.php?**

The user clicks on a picture at `index.php` which takes him to the

```
timeline.php
```

which is located at `subpages/timeline.php` and is basically the new index.php (like when you logged in into Facebook and the timeline appears).

It has a new CSS structure and also content which is generated through php. 
The content for the timeline.php is at

`/subpages/profiles/profilename/timelineprofilename.php`

Basically the user opens a php file in a php file

`(index.php <-> timeline.php <-> timelineprofilename1.php)`.

**2. How do I get the timelineprofilename1.php content into the timeline.php?**

So the link in the `index.php` (with content from landingpage.php) looks like this

```
index.php?page=timeline&name=harry
```

and with the following code I try to get the content of the userprofile, depending on the URL param:

```
*timeline.php*
<body>
 ...
<section>
<div>
  <?php


   if (isset($_GET['page']))      //check vor variables
      {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
      }
        else
           echo "DIDNT WORK1";      //if no value found
   if (isset_($_GET['name']))
      {
        $name = $_GET['name'];
      }
        else                        //if no value found
            echo "DIDNT WORK2";
   if (preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/', $page , $name))        //check var for not allowed parameter (Is this even possible like this?)
      {
        $inserted = include('subpages/profiles/'.$name.'/'. $page.$name.'.php');   //check if there is a page, matching the page = Val and name = val e.g.: subpages/profiles/kay/timelinekay.php
        if (!$inserted)
            echo('Requested page was not found.');
            }
             else
                 echo('Invalid param!!');
    ?>

    </div>
    </section<
    </body>
```

When I open the url `index.php?page=timeline&name=harry` the timeline shows up, but the shown php section fails with:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function isset_() in C:\xampp\htdocs\subpages\timeline.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(31): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\subpages\timeline.php on line 34
```

Line 34 points to the   `if (isset_($_GET['name']))` query.

Comment: because the function is `isset()` not `isset_()`.  Otherwise I think your question is far too broad.

Comment: I'll try to separate them. thx.